# Trying to resolve this Java problem: finding palindromes (String)

Tags: java

I'm a "noob" Java student who is trying to complete the next problem, it's about finding palindromes. I've tried to do it but i can't get the solution! As I said I'm "noob", I only use the "standard" public class, I don't know how to explain it, but I'm still learning, so I don't know even how the functions work, you can make it complex, but not too complex xD. Here it is, thank you people:

> A palindrome is a word that is typed the same way from left to right and also from right to left, for example: Y, EE, ALA, ANNA, ROTOR or AAAAAA

> Ask a word to the user and identify if it is a palindrome or not, and also show how many diferent palindromes the word has inside.

> I/O examples:

```
Write the word:
rotor

Palindromes found apart from the 5 letters that compose the word:
rotor
oto

Total number of palindromes: 7
```

```
Write the word:
rotoro

Palindromes found apart from the 5 letters that compose the word:
rotor
oto
oro

Total number of palindromes: 9
```

```
Write the word:
AAAAAAAABAA

Palindromes found apart from the 11 letters that compose the word:
AA
AAA
AAAA
AAAAA
AAAAAA
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
AA
AAA
AAAA
AAAAA
AAAAAA
AAAAAAA
AA
AAA
AAAA
AAAAA
AAAAAA
AA
AAA
AAAA
AAAAA
AA
AAA
AAAA
AA
AAA
AA
AABAA
ABA
AA

Total number of palindromes: 31
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Write the word: ");
        String word = sc.next();

        sc.close();
        System.out.println();

        String subWord = "--";
        int increment = 0;
        int decrement = word.length();

        while (increment < decrement && subWord.length() > 1) {
            increment++;
            decrement--;
            subWord = word.substring(increment, decrement);

            for (int i = 0, j = subWord.length() - 1, f = 0, g = 1; f != g && i < j; i++, j--) {
                if (subWord.charAt(i) == subWord.charAt(j)) {
                    System.out.println(subWord);
                }

                g = f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can guide you in the right direction to solve this problem

Comment: okay, I'm new here, trying to learn also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly altered approach.  It eliminates unnecessary looping by controlling loop indices and threshold computations.  It compensates by initializing the count to the length of the initial string.  Note that this method is case sensitive.  So `aBA` would not be considered a palindrome.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] data = { "ROTOR", "ROTORO", "AAAAAAAABAA" };
   for (String str : data) {
      System.out.printf("%s  - %s%n", str,
            countPalindromes(str));
   }
}
```

prints

```
ROTOR  - 7
ROTORO  - 9
AAAAAAAABAA  - 42
```

```
public static int countPalindromes(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    int count = len; // initialize to number of known palindromes.
    for (int k = 0; k < len - 1; k++) {
        for (int i = k + 1; i < len; i++) {
            String test = str.substring(k, i + 1);
            if (isPalindrome(test)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
    
public static boolean isPalindrome(String a) {
    char[] ch = a.toCharArray();
    int len = ch.length;
    // compare characters from each end toward the middle
    for (int i = 0; i <= len / 2; i++) {
        if (ch[i] != ch[len - 1 - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm starting at coding, so I don't know how to execute your code xD, I run it but my IDE says me that is not executable. Help please and apologies :P

Comment: I will edit the first method so it contains the main entry point.  Then all you need to do is create a class and place those methods in the class.

Comment: Still not getting it :/ , I want the program show all the palindromes if the word entered is a palindrom, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Place `System.out.println(test);` inside the `if (isPalindrome(test)) {` block.

Comment: It was so easy that I hadn't seen it, omg now yes thanks, now that I have analysed more in depth your code I can understand more how Java works and how those "public static int/boolean" work! So those are the functions right? Called methods in Java?

Comment: Just curious why you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: I thought i could put more than one accepted answers, I'm new here sorry

Comment: No problem.  Accept whomever you want.  I was just curious about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not best perfomance solution, but this is intuitive clear.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countPalindromes("AAAAAAAABAA"));    // 42
}

public static int countPalindromes(String str) {
    int res = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= str.length(); j++)
            if (isPalindrome(str.substring(i, j)))
                res++;

    return res;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using dynamic programming. Not beginner friendly in any way but throwing it out nonetheless:

```
public int getNoPalindromes(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    int[][] cache = new int[len][len];
    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(int j = len - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            int subStrLen = j - i + 1;
            if(1 == subStrLen) {
                // any single character is a palindrome trivially
                cache[i][j] = 1;
            } else if(2 == subStrLen) {
                // for substrings with len = 2, just compare the two characters
                cache[i][j] = (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) ? 1 : 0;
            } else {
                //for larger substrings, compare the two chars and just see if the mid substring was already determined to be a palindrome
                cache[i][j] = (1 == cache[i + 1][j - 1] && (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j))) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        }
    }
     int cnt = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
             if(1 == cache[i][j]) {
                 cnt++;
             }
         }
     }
    return cnt;
}
```

The logic is: To determine if a string c1c2c3....ck is palindrome, you can check if c2c3...c(k-1) is a palindrome and if c1 == ck. Here's how `cache` looks for a string like abba:

```
  a b b a
a 1 0 0 1
b 0 1 1 0 
b 0 0 1 0
a 0 0 0 1
```

Observe how the matrix is being filled (bottom-up). `cache[len-1][len-1]` tells you if the complete string is a palindrome (if it's 1). This is the most optimal solution I can think of.

Comment: Ow it's interesting, hard for me but hmm I'll mess around with ur code hehe